# how to refresh google map after change map style?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'd like to refresh google maps after a style change.

I'm following this [basic styling example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-styled-simple)

But how do I swap/refresh/reload with/to the new style, after setting it via:

```js
// Enable the visual refresh
google.maps.visualRefresh = true;

function setMapStyle(mapStyle)
{
    map.setOptions({styles: mapStyle});   
}
```

Perhaps its possible to addListener on style options?

Comment: You don't need to refresh anything, your function should apply the new style and you should see the change. When not, there must be something wrong(e.g. `map` is not accessible inside the function or `mapStyles` is not valid)

Comment: aha had to turn that string into JSON.parse(mapStyle);

Comment: function setMapStyle(mapStyle)
{
    map.setOptions({styles: JSON.parse(mapStyle)});   
}